# Ensure connection

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using the **ssh.net** library to communicate with SFTP server.
In my application I have to download  and upload a lot of files to server.So I have to open and close connections many times.

I would like to know if it's better to open a single connection and always keep it open, as long as I finish my actions and then only close the connection. Will there be a security issue if I keep the connection open for a time? Maybe it would be better if I open and close connections every time when I need to download or upload file from SFTP?

Maybe connection opening and closing is more efficient (consumes less resources)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's arguably preferable to use a single SSH connection and stick with it until your work is done.

However, if you have to wait for a long time, e.g. to process data in-between, your connection may close anyway. To determine if a such a scenario reasonable [check](https://www.maketecheasier.com/keep-ssh-connections-alive-in-linux/) your SSH Server `ServerAliveInterval`.

Regarding your security concerns, [leaving a connection open](https://superuser.com/questions/540768/is-it-insecure-to-leave-open-an-ssh-connection) isn't any more of a risk than having SSH available in the first place.

A more crucial question is, how reliable is your SSH connection. Sometimes, after a while, the ssh connection may hang, or the tunnel may break down. `autossh` helps out to [monitor your tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open).

Comment: The answers in the linked SU question are not really correct. Of course it is more insecure to leave the SSH connection open, as longer the connection is opened, greater there's a chance that an attacker have enough time for a brute force attack. That's why there's a re-key mechanism in SSH. So if one chooses to keep SSH connection open long time, he/she must ensure that re-key happens regularly.

Comment: Of course, but we do not know the time frame we are talking about: minutes, hours, days, weeks? I things keep reasonable, and have a strong key you should be fine for now.